# What is the t in drwxrwxrwt or the value of t?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

`ls -al /` shows a folder:

`drwxrwxrwt  2 root root       4096 Feb 26 09:00 tmp`

What does the last character `t` mean in `drwxrwxrwt`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the sticky bit, see this page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit